# Blank Android Google Maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I know that this question is asked several times, but that didn't helped me.

When I run application on my phone, I get just blank screen with zoom in and zoom out controls.

So, here is my AndroidManifest.xml code:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.testgooglemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.testgooglemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


<application android:debuggable="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.testgooglemaps.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
       <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDoII86zBbwgdHr8qsI0TJqtAwsVihi7N4" />
       <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Here I check path to my debug keystore.

[image]

Here is how it looks, when I check for SHA1 fingerprint from cmd.

[image]

Here is how it looks, when I am creating new Android key on Google API Console:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If map is not loading , in most cases it's because of API key issue. It seems that you have followed the procedures. I can suggest you 2 things ,

1. Try using a different debug or release keystore file and generate a new API ley from Google Apps API console.
2. Update your JDK , that will eventually update your keytool.exe . So, if it's due to keytool issue then this may help you.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried first opion, and I failed. :) Currently I am using JDK 1.6, I will try to switch to JDK 1.7, is that ok?

Comment: I get this error when I try to set Java compiler JDK to 1.7: Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.

Comment: Keep compiler compliance level to 6.0 , that's fine. I am telling to install the latest JDK .

Comment: okey, I am downloading latest JDK, and then I will reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem one time and the solution was to downgrade the **keytool**.

Indeed, by changing the version I got a completely different key.

Bu I will not be able to give you the version.
On the others topics, they said to use the Keytool from jdk1.6.

Hope this will help

Comment: I tried to delete current debug.keystore and I got a new keystore with new SHA-1, and also I created a new Android key on Google API, but I am stil facing same problem.

Comment: Can you please explain how to downgrade keytool?

Comment: I made a new search but it seems you have to download a new JDK, but I'm not remember having do that...

Comment: I am using JDK 1.6, and I get this error when I try to set Java compiler JDK to 1.7: Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.

Comment: Changing the JDK of your android project is useless. You have to use a different keytool binary (which is in your JDK/JRE? folder inside your HDD)

Comment: I am downloading latest JDK, and then I will install it again.

Comment: Have you got the solution if not let me know.

Answer (score 0):

See here,just change the api key with your key in manifest file and follow these steps:
and **make sure that generate api key with package name which is mentioned in android manifest file and your google_play_services_lib project should be present in your project's work space only.**

Manifest file:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.geeklabs.map.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="replace with your API key"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
    package com.geeklabs.map;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

After got this let me know.